# API issue | URL with parameter

Tags: javascript, api

I have an issue with my Delete function, it is deleting always the last data and not the desired data.

Here's my API - DELETE function:

**Function to delete the data**

```
app.delete("/api/theTasks/:id", (req, res) => {
    let taskToRemove = Items.find(p => p.id == parseInt(req.params.id));
    let index = Items.indexOf(taskToRemove);
    Items.splice(index, 1);
    res.json(taskToRemove);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

1. find also return `undefined` If it does not find the item.
2. when you search for the undefined index it'll return `-1`
3. if you pass `-1` to `splice` It'll always remove the last element.

**Use array filter,**

```
app.delete("/api/theTasks/:id", (req, res) => {
  const result = Items.filter((p) => p.id === parseInt(req.params.id));

  if (result.length === 0) res.status(404).json({ error: "Item not found" });
  res.json(result);
});
```

Comment: The endpoint is supposed to return the deleted item.

Comment: Here's my code, should I pass the variable on the URL? 
async function deleteData(taskDescription) {


    console.log("deleteing data");

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "http://localhost:5050/api/theTasks/:";

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the task is not found and `index` ends up being `-1`, so you end up calling:

```
Items.splice(-1, 1);
```

which removes the last element of `Items`.

You can fix the issue by checking if the item was found and only deleting it if that is true.

```
app.delete("/api/theTasks/:id", (req, res) => {
    let taskToRemove = Items.find(p => p.id == parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (taskToRemove) {
        let index = Items.indexOf(taskToRemove);
        Items.splice(index, 1);
        res.json(taskToRemove);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Item not found' });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

get index is -1;
you should check it before splice;
or use filter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).